# How to get all results for api/issues/search (not just first 500)?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I am trying to use the SonarQube web service API `api/issues/search` to extract the information of all issues. But I see that the maximum number of results from the API is only 500 with filters like pageSize.

Is there a different way of using this API so that I can get all the issues in the resultlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web service results are paginated. Use `ps` (page size) and `p` to step through the result set.

That said, there's a hard limit of 10k.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I did use the ps and p parameters to step through and recursively get all the issues. What's with the 10k limit? Are you saying if i have 12000 results i cant fetch them all using the API? IS there a way i can also get the SQALE rating using the API?

Comment: Rating of the project or of individual files? Either way though, that's really a separate question, isn't it? :)

Comment: Agreed :) its a separate question. I was looking at getting the SQALE rating for the project